# Maquina virutal de ubuntu cliente no arranca, error : kernel panic

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualización, cliente

Os comento, cuando inicio la maquina virtual de ubuntu ( ubuntu cliente 18.04) me salta el error de Kernel Panic, he estado investigando y no he econtrado nada que lo solucione, he estado probando varias cosas pero nada, no sirve ni reiniciar, ni apagar ni restarurar instantaneas. Os pongo captura del error completo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación, tal como lo establece el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta podría formularse en [su] o en [ubuntu.SE].